# If I put on clothes with dry najasah (dry impurities), will my wudu be broken?

Tags: wudu, taharah

For example, let's say I'm wearing fresh clothes and then I perform wudu and offer salah. After I complete my salah, I change my clothes and put on trousers that have traces of dry urine on it. So, when the time of next salah comes, I put the fresh clothes back on before praying salah.

But do I have to perform wudu again? Because if I remember correctly, dry urine (or any dry najasah) does not break your wudu.

Comment: Well wudu is a ritual washing it doesn't necessary need to make you clean! But to pray you must have performed wudu (or a similar ritual cleaning) and have clean clothes and a clean underground where you pray on and that's fine!

Comment: See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/is-it-permissible-to-re-use-the-water-that-has-been-already-used-by-myself-for http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/tahaara-and-waswas/30522?s=6|0.0703#30522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If I put on clothes with dry najasah (dry impurities), will my wudu be broken?

Touching or coming in contact with dry impurities does not break wudu. So, if you put on impure clothes, that does not break your wudu.

> Merely touching impurities does not break wudhu. (Fatāwa Mahmodiyyah, Vol.5,Pg.74)

Comment: I'd like to add that if one prays with najis clothes, his prayer could be considered as invalid (for details see here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30920/is-istinja-necessary-for-ablution/30953#30953)